# Use where like for relative search in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am doing data search function in php . I use `mongoDB`. I have a table `user`:

```
id        name         status
1         tèo           1
2         tý            2
```

In `UserRepository.php` :

```
<?php


namespace App\Repositories\Backend\MongoDB;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Repositories\MongoDBBaseRepository;

class UserRepository extends MongoDBBaseRepository
{
    public function model()
    {
        return MoviePassContent::class;
    }
    public function search($keyword)
    {
        $search = $this->model->where('name', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')->get()->toArray();
        // I tried more of these ways, but it still doesn't work
        // $search = $this->model->where('name', 'like', $keyword.'%')->get()->toArray();
        // $search = $this->model->where('name', 'like', '%'.$keyword)->get()->toArray();
    }
}
```

If the `$keyword` I enter is : `tèo`, the result is correct. But when I enter `$keyword` as `teo` or `t` it returns null. Where did I go wrong. Please give me your opinion. Thank you.

Comment: iirc (MySQL) fulltextsearch by default requires at least two (or even three?) characters to work. Can be adjusted in the settings though.

Comment: This depends on your DBMS, and how they handle accent sensitivity. It's not a Laravel setting to get this to work so we need more details on your DBMS, table/collection structure and encodings/collations

Answer (score 0):

It's not related to Laravel or PHP. It all depends on your database. Try to utilize a different collation charset on your database.

Example below changes your collation and charset to utf32. Careful, make sure to backup your database to prevent any data loss! This action may cause partial or full data loss:

```
ALTER DATABASE your_db_name
    CHARACTER SET utf32]
    COLLATE utf32_general_ci
```

You may tweak it to find the best fit for you, it depends on what kind of data you're inserting into the db.

Another safer alternative is to mitigate it on application layer. Define a scope which will help with special character conversions.

As for the: "searching by 't' but not appearing" issue, it seems like DBMS config problem. Even though it usually applies for `FULLTEXT` search, there might be some setting about min-length regarding `LIKE` queries.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `jenssegers/laravel-mongodb` then you can achieve this with `->options` to your query:

```
        $search = $this->model
             ->where('name', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')
             ->options([ 
                 'collation' => [
                    'locale' => 'en',
                    'strength' => 1  
                  ]
            ])->get()->toArray();
```

Check https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.3/reference/collation/ for more details on the collation option